# Optional Claim ctry not working for some users

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

when we trying to get ctry optional claim from azure ad then It's added to token for some users
and not added for others and it's showing ctry claim in ClaimsPrincipal Claim Class but not showing in Id token that has received from azure ad after authenticated user.

Configuration in Manifest file:

```
 "optionalClaims": {
    "idToken": [
      {
        "name": "ctry",
        "source": null,
        "essential": false,
        "additionalProperties": []
      }
    ]
  }
```

So, Any One can help me to find
how ctry Claim Mapping the Country on azure
and how many sources ctry can use for mapping country
like it's map only from user Properties or anywhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Note** that: If the field value is a two-letter country or region code, such as FR, JP, SZ, and so on, Azure AD returns the **`ctry`** optional claim.

I created an **Azure AD user and updated the country field** like below:

[image]

I generated **authorization code** by using below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope= https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

When I decoded the token, the **country claim is displayed** like below:

[image]

I updated the **country field as `Japan` instead of two letter code**:

[image]

I generated the access token and when decoded **country claim isn't displayed** like below:

[image]

Hence **to resolve the issue**, check the below:

- Make sure that the country field is updated as two letter code.
- Check if the user country field is empty or not.
- If still the issue persists, check the sign-in logs for the error.

**Reference:**

[Provide optional claims to Azure AD apps - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims)

Comment: Thank You So Much Rukmini,
Your Solution worked ,
If the country attribute is not set or is set to a different format (e.g., the full country name), the ctry claim will not be included in the token or may be mapped incorrectly.
It is also worth noting that the mapping of the ctry claim to the country attribute can be customized in the Azure AD tenant using the ImmutableID or SourceAnchor attributes, which can be used to specify a different attribute in the user's profile to use for the country claim mapping.